# How to detect if a UITextField was cleared using the UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

there is a `UITextField` which has a clear button implemented as follows:

```
myUITextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing
```

How do I detect if the `UITextField` was cleared using the clear button?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only detect if UITextField is empty. Is there specific reason you want to detect this specific clear button?